# Allocation as default initialization

Tags: c++, constructor

Say I have a `struct` (or class) with a dynamic array, its length, and a constructor:

```
struct array {
    int l;
    int* t;
    array(int length);
};

array::array(int length) {
    l=length;
    t=new int[l];
}
```

I assume everything so far is legal: this is how I would write it (although it maybe not be the only way to do things), but I have seen the following code, that somewhat seems to work:

```
struct array {
    int l;
    int* t = new int[l];
    array(int length);
}

array::array(int length) {
    l=length;
}
```

It looks bad, so I wonder if this works out of sheer luck and undefined behaviors, or if there is some internal rule that makes this code work fine.

Comment: don't use 'l' as a variable name, It's easily confused with the number '1',

Comment: @regomodo: I'd rather tell people not to use fonts (for coding) that make it easy to confuse `I`, `l` and `1`. :-)

Comment: id rather people read "Clean Code" instead

Comment: @Heinzi Or maybe stop using single letter variables damnit.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This code is not correct.

`int* t = new int[l];` will happen before `l=length;`, thus reading the uninitialized variable `l`. Member initializers are handled *before* the constructor's body runs.

```
array::array(int length) : l{length} {}
```

instead would work because `l` is declared before `t`.

**However**, doing this "by hand" is a bad idea to begin with. You should be using `std::vector`.

Answer (score 10):

The 2nd code snippet might have undefined behavior.

The data members are initialized at the order of how they're declared. For class `array`, when `t` is initialized `l` is not initialized yet. For objects with automatic and dynamic storage duration `l` will be initialized to indeterminate value, then the usage of `l` (i.e. `new int[l]`) leads to UB.

Note that `l=length;` inside the body of the constructor is just assignment; the initialization of data members has been finished before that.

BTW: With member initializer list the 1st code snippet chould be rewritten as

```
array::array(int length) : l(length), t(new int[l]) {
}
```

Comment: Why do you say "might"? It does have UB, unconditionally.

Comment: @Ruslan Because for static or thread-local objects `l` will get [zero initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization) at first.

Comment: @Ruslan I suppose, since a program with undefined behaviour can make _anything_ happen, we could argue that one possible outcome of this program is making the code well-defined ;)